# HTML Anchor mailto Subject encoding issue in Outlook

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, mailto

I have this anchor element which uses `mailto:` to send the page as an email.
The website is bilingual (English/Arabic), the English version works great, however the Arabic version ***on some machines*** has an issue with the encoding of the Subject characters which are sent in Arabic, here is my tag:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=رسالة بالعربية&amp;body=blahblahblah">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
</a>
```

Upon clicking this link on some machines, Outlook starts but the subject appears to be gibberish.
I also tried to encode the text in the subject to no avail:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=&#1585;&#1587;&#1575;&#1604;&#1577; &#1576;&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;&amp;body=blahblahblah">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
</a>
```

Is there anything I can do on the page or on the broken machine to fix this?

Or is there any other way to achieve this without facing the same issue?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set an encoding for the html-Page? If not, some browsers may use the default-encoding of the operating system, resulting in correct display, while others may not.

Try adding the following tag to your "html-head" Area

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

(your tool/editor needs to safe it in that format that it works)

Comment: The page does have this meta tag, it has no effect on this issue.

Comment: Can you check the encoding of the file? If your meta-tag differs from the actual file encoding, this can also cause errors. A freeware tool to do this would be for example notepad++. It shows the file-encoding in the status bar at the lower right corner

Comment: The file's encoding is UTF-8, and if that was the case then, why does it work perfectly well on most machines and not on the others?

Comment: Each browser has a default-encoding option, which could have been configured differently.This could result in different interpretation in different browsers. You can find these option for example in the Internet Explorer in the Menu (freely translated) View -> Encoding, Firefox View -> Characterencoding, in Safari View -> Textencoding. You could check if the settings differ on your test machines, but if the file-encoding is correct and the same as in the meta-Tag like you say, I don't think this should matter :(

Comment: I checked the browser settings, all the machines have Unicode (UTF-8) as Encoding .. I am running out of thought about this. Anyway Thanks for your help @Brandtware.